# Debugging dkim=fail using sendmail+dkim-milter

Tags: sendmail, dkim

I'm setting up a CentOS server with the sendmail MTA to send DKIM-signed mail (sending domain is @brighter.do).  I have succeeded in routing mails through the dkim milter; however, they arrive at my GMail account with dkim=fail authentication results and no further information.  How do I begin to debug this (besides Googling 'debug failed dkim' and other such related terms)?

I used the config described in [these](http://www.mylinuxtips.info/linuxtipstutorials/setup-dkim-keys-with-sendmail/) instructions.  The only additional config changes I made were adding my app user to `/etc/mail/trusted-users`, adding `EXTRA_FLAGS=-R` to `/etc/sysconfig/dkim-milter`, and switching Canonicalization to `relaxed/relaxed` (which didn't appear to change anything).  I've verified that the key is 2048 bits using ssh-keygen -l -f app1.  (It seems that a too-small key can cause GMail to reject a valid DKIM signature but that doesn't appear to be my problem.)

The contents of my relevant DNS records are:

```
APP1._DOMAINKEY.BRIGHTER.DO. TXT k=rsa; p=AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC3pJ4UJW/KBQ2D6N/6kl37yqJ0F4NcKPGApyHw4wl2zohdOPp8rELvQnRgvmQUMu3hrgicD9W9LbnGx/CzakZAA4RcJk9kI51v+Y8L5j3lZURFC1ZIXoRFgfafyo31XN3rc+V0hNMXUGcxVI09oYtyS+2AuC9cULP4Nu030I3yYFd2NOwmKPY57PU3ybwGKEvuWsB/9PyWC6KVlULlkg7TB
APP1._DOMAINKEY.BRIGHTER.DO. TXT CwbMnGyavwIeoJpNlb1fINdDGWDAJvfTTpMGvIkQAehknbgBqL4IgciWQ/2xw6bMhma7MRJHzZsd7JfbNramQIpsxX6hZUkZja6HpoFJzBi1vbnLcM2n8Xhat/A1Q/F
_DOMAINKEY.BRIGHTER.DO. TXT o=~ r=angela@brighter.do
```

The headers I'm getting are:

```
Delivered-To: angela@brighter.do
Received: by 10.140.42.166 with SMTP id c35csp248278qga;
        Wed, 23 Mar 2016 14:10:12 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.98.72.213 with SMTP id q82mr7347661pfi.164.1458767412258;
        Wed, 23 Mar 2016 14:10:12 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <info@brighter.do>
Received: from DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM (outbound.brighter.do. [54.201.111.245])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m22si6801929pfi.43.2016.03.23.14.10.12
        for <angela@brighter.do>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 23 Mar 2016 14:10:12 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@brighter.do designates 54.201.111.245 as permitted sender) client-ip=54.201.111.245;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=fail header.i=@brighter.do;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@brighter.do designates 54.201.111.245 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@brighter.do
Received: from DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id u2NLAB8k007870
    for <angela@brighter.do>; Wed, 23 Mar 2016 21:10:11 GMT
X-DKIM: Sendmail DKIM Filter v2.8.3 DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM u2NLAB8k007870
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=brighter.do; s=app1;
    t=1458767411; bh=HiluaVoCYKZyFY1h3gE73EqhCFuKBJzE8SqwhrLX5/c=;
    h=Date:Message-Id:To:Subject:MIME-Version:From;
    b=RfNNbBaAUNX+y3cdSqb+NkgC8GHa0wd/vV4LC72DQ8jbSWIHfqxZD6Qi3xGtKVnyU
     2j9FDAtI7X1B7dsPuFIw9F5m+1YoFuV+/3vCQ/zsXxCoExwml7DrxnYuWI0e5MeKma
     3K4T+R/tpNgKYVSU00RNCorLsvyia/fD8+wFTY4ZyoYOTZ4tK6gwcO4loPERiPAAOL
     HI11YagXgreCk3efJXanF8Df9ALLmTZMjMLXHHIHnSsypzhtEXYmua+EWQEZzIiVis
     paAmh9w8sRfeFww4PraRN7Caxznm51ZUIecdST29xRL276LsEgb5Nsy6TIEJyOov/N
     7AilYKXwuotHg==
Received: (from ec2-user@localhost)
    by DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id u2NLABrt007869;
    Wed, 23 Mar 2016 21:10:11 GMT
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 21:10:11 GMT
Message-Id: <201603232110.u2NLABrt007869@DUALSTACK.PROD-API-478862527.US-WEST-2.ELB.AMAZONAWS.COM>
To: angela@brighter.do
Subject: Test message
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:PushComponent.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Brighter <info@brighter.do>
```

Note: since I know almost nothing about e-mail admin, it's possible that I'm omitting some key details here.  In that event please help me improve the question by mentioning what additional info would be useful - e.g., other config files to include.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is two months old, but it is a top Google search result for the subject so I figured it deserved an answer.

I don't know what your second and third TXT entries are for. I have DKIM working properly now and I only have a TXT entry similar to your first one.

I followed instructions from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy) when setting up DKIM on Ubuntu, but it didn't work properly right out of the box. I found [this page](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/How+to+Debug+DKIM/17528/) to be very helpful in debugging my DKIM problem.

To verify that your DNS TXT entry is being read correctly, type the following on the linux command line:

```
dig +short TXT APP1._domainkey.brighter.do
```

I'm using GoDaddy for DNS and I didn't need the domain name as part of my domain key string. Instead, I just needed the subdomain portion in the name field, as follows:

```
mail._domainkey
```

(I'm using "mail" instead of "app1" to specify my domain key.)

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem. Once you get DKIM working properly, you'll realize that it's not that confusing. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was you had 3 DNS records instead of one and did not use parentheses.

```
dig +short TXT APP1._domainkey.brighter.do
" v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAt6SeFCVvygUNg+jf+pJd+8qidBeDXCjxgKch8OMJds6IXTj6fKxC70J0YL5kFDLt4a4InA/VvS25xsfws2pGQAOEXCZPZCOdb/mPC+Y95WVERQtWSF6ERYH2n8qN9Vzd63PldITTF1BnMVSNPaGLckvtgLgvXFCz+DbtN9CN8mBXdjTsJij2Oez1N8m8Bi" "hL7lrAf/T8lguilZVC5ZIO0wQsGzJxsmr8CHqCaTZW9XyDXQxlgwCb3006TBryJEAHoZJ24Aai+CIHIlkP9scOmzIZmuzESR82bHeyX2za2pkCKbMV+oWVJGY2uh6aBScwYtb25y3DNp/F4WrfwNUPxQIDAQAB"
```

So now you see you have a single entry with two strings "". When adding DKIM records remember that one line is 255 characters. I tried to put all in one line and wondered why DKIM failed in google. In some webpanels you are limited to 255 chars. The [trick is to use parentheses](http://hack.limbicmedia.ca/how-to-split-dns-dkim-records-properly/). Check if the system is not removing them. Good providers like [OVH](https://www.ovh.com/fr/) have a special input option for DKIM records. When you have a look on [opendkim](http://opendkim.org/) and [follow the debian setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy), than you notice the txt files you can use to set the dns records. They also contain the parentheses.

One more thought: look in the dmarc report always which selector is tested. Google for example, will tell you in the report. I created the dkim with another selector I thought.